# Does google+/facebook login provide support for roles?

Tags: android, web, google-plus, google-play-services, facebook-android-sdk

I am working on a app that uses google+ and facebook login as user authentication.

I want to introduce different roles of users (ex- admin,user,product owner etc.)

A "product owner" will be able to see/ modify a different set of features than a  "user" and so on.

Does google+/facebook sign-in support such role based user login or I will have to write my own sign up process?

Comment: I have not read any of such thing in facebook sdk documentation , I hope same in Google plus.

Comment: G+ does not do this either. Maybe you could use some sort of profile information, but that's entirely dependent on the user. You really ought to have that information stored on your end (a unique identifier for the user and what role they are), so that when they login you can identify and allot them the appropriate privileges.

Comment: These services provide authentication, not authorization. If you want authorization, you need to do it yourself.